# How to access code wrapped in define directives of other Assembly?

Tags: unity-game-engine, preprocessor-directive

I am stuck and hope someone is familiar with `assemblies` and `platform-dependent` compilation.
I can't call classes in other assemblies which are wrapped with **preprocessor directives / define directives**. Without having directives it goes fine. Also, I can't address code in platform-limited assemblies.
Is this intentional behavior or is there something wrong?

**Test class:**

```cs
public class Main
{
    public void Test()
    {
        /// Classes In Same Assembly 
        /// ---------------------
        UnrestrictedClassSameAssembly.Test(); // Works as intended
        #if WINDOWS_UWP 
        UWPClassSameAssembly.Test(null); // Works as intended
        #endif

        /// Classes In Other Assembly
        /// ---------------------
        UnrestrictedClassOtherAssembly.Test();  // Works as intended

        // Does NOT work as intended
        // The name UWPClassOtherAssembly does not exist in the current context
        #if WINDOWS_UWP 
        UWPClassOtherAssembly.Test(null);
        #endif

        /// Class In WSA Assembly
        /// ---------------------
        ///

        // Does NOT work as intended
        // The name ClassUWPAssembly does not exist in the current context
        #if WINDOWS_UWP
        ClassUWPAssembly.Test(null);
        #endif
    }
}
```

**SameAssemblyClasses.cs:**

```cs
//Is in MainAssembly
public static class UnrestrictedClassSameAssembly
{
    public static void Test(){ }
}

#if WINDOWS_UWP
public static class UWPClassSameAssembly
{
    public static void Test(Windows.Storage.StorageFolder sf){ }
}
#endif
```

**OtherAssemblyClasses.cs:**

```cs
//Is in OtherAssembly
public static class UnrestrictedClassOtherAssembly
{
    public static void Test() { }
}

#if WINDOWS_UWP
public static class UWPClassOtherAssembly
{
    public static void Test(Windows.Storage.StorageFolder sf) { }
}
#endif
```

**UWPClass.cs:**

```cs
//Is in UWPAssembly
public static class ClassUWPAssembly
{
    public static void Test(Windows.Storage.StorageFolder sf) { }
}
```

**Assembly definitions:**

```
{
    "name": "MainAssembly",
    "rootNamespace": "",
    "references": [
        "OtherAssembly",
        "UWPAssembly"
    ],
    "includePlatforms": [],
    "excludePlatforms": [],
    "allowUnsafeCode": false,
    "overrideReferences": false,
    "precompiledReferences": [],
    "autoReferenced": true,
    "defineConstraints": [],
    "versionDefines": [],
    "noEngineReferences": false
}
{
    "name": "OtherAssembly",
    "rootNamespace": "",
    "references": [],
    "includePlatforms": [],
    "excludePlatforms": [],
    "allowUnsafeCode": false,
    "overrideReferences": false,
    "precompiledReferences": [],
    "autoReferenced": true,
    "defineConstraints": [],
    "versionDefines": [],
    "noEngineReferences": false
}
{
    "name": "UWPAssembly",
    "rootNamespace": "",
    "references": [],
    "includePlatforms": [
        "WSA"
    ],
    "excludePlatforms": [],
    "allowUnsafeCode": false,
    "overrideReferences": false,
    "precompiledReferences": [],
    "autoReferenced": true,
    "defineConstraints": [],
    "versionDefines": [],
    "noEngineReferences": false
}
```

Comment: Well I guess you can access the code if it is compiled for your platform ... you won't be able to use it if you are on a platform that code is not compiled for either because of the preprocessors or because the entire assembly is excluded on that platform ... Maybe I don't quite understand your question?

Comment: Which Unity version are you using and where does the define `WINDOWS_UWP` come from? Seemingly it is not in sync with the WSA platform?

Comment: The project is based on the unity version 2020.3.20f1. 

```WINDOWS_UWP``` is specified in the [unity docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html).

I need it because I work with the ```Windows.Storage``` namespace and ```il2cpp``` to access data on the Hololens.

Comment: `UNITY_WSA_10_0` -> `#define directive for Universal Windows Platform. Additionally WINDOWS_UWP is defined when compiling C# files against .NET Core.` ... I guess that is simply not the case for your situation?

Comment: The build settings are set to ```UWP```. 

When I change the directives from ```WINDOWS_UWP``` to ```UNITY_WSA``` or ```UNITY_WSA_10_0```, ```UWPClassOtherAssembly``` comes in context. However, it tries to load the ```Windows``` namespace in the editor environment where it is not present.
And ```ClassUWPAssembly``` still does not work though.

Comment: It looks like ```MainAssembly.Player```-Project is unable to resolve the ```UWPAssembly```-Assembly.

Comment: Do you get the errors in the editor, when trying to build the project or on runtime on the target device?

Comment: The problem appears in the editor. [Here](https://github.com/develmusa/UnityPlatformDependentAssemblyProblem) is an example project with the problem.

Comment: where do you get the errors originally? I mean when using `#if WINDOWS_UWP` ?

Comment: When I try to access anything with a ```#if WINDOWS_UWP``` directive in another assembly.

Comment: yeah but I mean .. in the editor? when trying to build? on the target device? For me it compiles just fine on both standalone and UWP as target platform and it builds just fine for both ... (only reverted all `#if UNITY_WSA_10` to `#if WINDOWS_UWP`)